# Functions returns false even when the if statement is true

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/

My solution:

```
static int count = 0; 
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(happyNumber(19));
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}

public static bool happyNumber(int  a)
{
    double result = 0;
    Stack<int> stapel = new Stack<int>(); 
    //Split the integer into single digits and save them in a stack
    while (a.ToString().Count() > 1)
    {
        stapel.Push(a % 10);
        a = a / 10;
    }
    if (a.ToString().Count() == 1)
    {
        stapel.Push(a);
    }
    // Add the square of the digits to get the result
    foreach (var item in stapel)
    {
        result += Math.Pow((double)item, 2);
    }
    // Check if it's a happy number
    if(result == 1.0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // counter to stop if it is a endless loop
    else if(count < 100)
    {
        count++;
        happyNumber((int)result);
    }
    return false;
}
```

So the input 19 is a happy number and the if clauses is true in the 4th run. 
You can set a breakpoint at `if(result == 1.0)` to check it. So why my function returns false instead?

Comment: check if(result == 1)

Comment: Yes, it is still true but my function will return false,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unnecessarily casting to a double. Make `result` an `int` rather than a `double` (or make it a `long` if you're concerned the result will be too large for an `int`). Replace the call to `Math.Pow` with manually squaring `item`, like so:

```
result += item * item;
```

The reason that control flow does not enter the `if(result == 1.0)` block is due to the way floating-point values are internally represented. Testing for equality between `double`s is problematic, and so (in this scenario) you should probably just avoid using them entirely as they are unneeded.

You also have a recursive call here:

```
happyNumber((int)result);
```

However, that call does nothing, as you're not actually doing anything with the return value. Consider replacing that line with:

```
return happyNumber((int)result);
```

This will return the value of the recursive call, rather than just discarding it.

Comment: I'm gonna change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is recursive, but you don't do anything with the result of the recursive call.

If you change:

```
happyNumber((int)result);
```

To:

```
return happyNumber((int)result);
```

Then your result for 19 is `true`.  There are potentially other issues with the comparison of floating point numbers, but that's probably your main problem!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your happyNumber method calls itself (3rd last line) and then from this call it hits the `return true` line - but that only returns one step up the stack to the happyNumber method.... which then hits `return false`.